# Why are the deviance residuals in my binomial GLM all zeroes?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, residuals, overdispersion, deviance

I am currently trying to run a binomial GLM to investigate the influence of temperature (factor: 5 levels 20, 23, 26, 29, 32 degrees Celsius) and species (factor: 2 levels HA and AP) on the likelihood of individuals moving from one life-stage to the next. Below is my model for the number of individuals moving from the egg stage to the first larval stage and its associated summary output:

```r
eggmodelA <- glm(cbind(No.hatched, No.eggs.added-No.hatched) ~ 
    Temperature*Species, data=eggto1st.1, 
    family = binomial(link="logit"))
summary(eggmodelA)
```

```r
Call:
glm(formula = cbind(No.2nd, No.first - No.2nd) ~ Temperature * 
    Species, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = X1stto2nd.1, 
    weights = No.first)

Deviance Residuals: 
 [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)              1.85630    0.07906  23.481  < 2e-16 ***
Temperature23            0.03455    0.09278   0.372  0.70959    
Temperature26           -0.97210    0.08599 -11.305  < 2e-16 ***
Temperature29           -0.67067    0.08295  -8.085 6.22e-16 ***
Temperature32           -1.16315    0.08738 -13.312  < 2e-16 ***
SpeciesHA                0.47098    0.11112   4.238 2.25e-05 ***
Temperature23:SpeciesHA  0.41076    0.14714   2.792  0.00524 ** 
Temperature26:SpeciesHA  2.02070    0.12501  16.164  < 2e-16 ***
Temperature29:SpeciesHA  1.44574    0.12565  11.506  < 2e-16 ***
Temperature32:SpeciesHA  1.88040    0.16012  11.744  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance:  5.0966e+03  on 9  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: -2.1472e-13  on 0  degrees of freedom
AIC: 2449.2

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Would anyone be able to explain to me why the deviance residuals are all zeroes?

Also, when I try to calculate theta (residual deviance/ residual d.f) to check for overdispersion I get a value of infinity. Would anyone be able to explain to me why this is?

Edit 1 - Here is the data that I am using:

```r
Temperature  Species  No.eggs.added   No.hatched
32           AP                 176           57
32           HA                 208           44 
29           AP                 162           94 
29           HA                 185           93 
26           AP                 139           65 
26           HA                 165          121 
23           AP                  69           61 
23           HA                  71           51 
20           AP                  56           37 
20           HA                  56           45
```

Comment: You have saturated the model with parameters. Note your residual deviance has zero degrees of freedom as well. If you dropped the interaction you would solve the statistical issue but whether that corresponds to a meaningful scientific question I do not know.

Comment: What is your sample size?

Comment: @The_old_man I have added the data that I am using for this model

Comment: @mdewey I would like to keep the interaction if possible so is there an alternative analysis method I could use?

Comment: WHy is temperature a factor variable?

Comment: @Dave Temperature is a factor because individuals were kept at one of five constant temperatures throughout the experiment.

Comment: That sounds like a number to me: 23 is 3 more than 20; 32 is 9 more than 23, etc.

Comment: @Dave Would temperature not be discrete still in the case of this study design as the temperature couldn't be anything but these values?

Comment: It’s definitely discrete, but discrete is not the same as categorical/factor. // It seems like you could save some parameters by modeling temperature linearly. Yes, that removes the opportunity for increase/decrease/increase-type of behavior, but that can be remedied in other ways, should it need to be.

Comment: A simpler model supposes the relationship between the outcome and the temperature is a function given by a theory.  Absent any theory, it's natural to try -- in order -- a constant (that is, no relationship) and then a linear relationship.  You can test whether that improves over the constant and you can also test the goodness of fit.  Your experiment does not permit you to estimate separate values for each temperature you provided (except in the trivial sense that you can fit the data perfectly).

Comment: @whuber Could you elaborate a little bit please as I'm a little rusty with my statistical and R knowledge. Does this mean coding temperature as a continuous variable? Could I then include species and their interaction after this? I apologize if I am not understanding you correctly

Comment: You are understanding me correctly.   Yes, you could include the interaction with species, but your experiment is so small that this is really pushing it unless the interaction is very strong or theoretically called for.  You will find that temperature alone is the only significant variable (and that including a quadratic term in temperature yields better improvement than including species).  BTW, your model formula conflicts with your data: they don't have the same variable names.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for clarifying. I am still interested in looking at the impact of species so would a better alternative to including the interaction and species in the same model as temperature be to run two separate models (one for each species)?

Comment: That won't help you at all.  You have to live with the limitations of your experiment.